# HP Proliant DL380 G7 won't power on, UID light works, ethernet lights blinking, power button solid orange

Tags: hp-proliant, power-supply-unit

Momentary press and long press of power button does nothing.

Can get in through iLO but pressing the button there does nothing.

This started after our block had a power failure but all our servers are surge protected and no other server had this issue.

Is it a power supply problem?  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you physically unplugged the server for a few minutes? Also, could be a fried motherboard or power supply. Surge protection doesn't help much without some sort of line conditioning.

Comment: Just tried swapping out the power supplies and no dice, same behavior.

Comment: What do the iLO logs show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You likely have a fried (something) on your motherboard. You'll need to call HP to get support or maybe even warranty replacement. Hopefully they have some diagnostic process that can help, but this is very doubtful.

Does your motherboard have replaceable voltage regulators near the processor or power supply input? One of these going bad could cause the symptoms you describe, as well.

Surge protection alone isn't enough, especially with servers. Good battery-based line conditioning is almost necessary with modern servers.

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure it's toast

Answer (score 2):

Either the motherboard is fried or, more likely, the power distribution board.
That PD board is the piece of electronics that combines the output of both the PSU's into one feed to the motherboard. It s quite susceptible to power surges.
Some dual-PSU Proliants have this as a separate board. In other models it's integrated in the motherboard itself.

In some cases the Proliant will work fine with just one PSU, but is unstable (spontaneous reboots) or won't boot at all if both PSU's are used. In that case it is certainly the PD board. (Was a recurring issue on DL380-G4 and G5 models.)

Answer (score 2):

In our company we have three server HP Proliant DL380 G7.

For one of them the button power off suddently didn't work when when did a shutdown.

We realize that the switch itself didn't have the same behavior as the two others which were working.

We unmount the small front panel where the button is, it's easy you don't need a screwwdriver.

And we saw that the switch inside was not place correctly, you can compare with the UUID button is the same type of electrical switch as the power on behind the front panel.

That's all.

Comment: We had the same issue just the past week, an old post but still, it has been running for years, went to upgrade memory since it is an esxi host and it would not power back on. Turned out to be the power button switch as noted by Vindic

Answer (score 0):

Same situation here, server is never power cycled. When it needed system internal cleaning and powered down, it would not power back up. Switch under the front cover was in a depressed state. There was dust bunny around the switch not allowing it to return to the released position. Cleaned out the dust and the switch functioned as it should. Thanks Vindic for your post! Made for a beginning to a good Friday!